# Laravel multipart form-data array validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, enctype

I've created a pretty basic form which contains two fields of array of file type.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="{{ url("check") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" files="true">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input type="file" name="file[]">
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

I've added the enctype attribute for submission, however Laravel's validation system seems to not work properly.
Indeed because errors are **displayed for one field only** :

```
{
  "name": [
    "file"
  ],
  "error": [
    "The file field is required."
  ]
}
```

**I was expecting something like that** (it displays when I remove the enctype attribute)

```
{
  "name": [
    "file.0",
    "file.1"
  ],
  "error": [
    "The file.0 must be a file of type: pdf, docx, odt.",
    "The file.1 must be a file of type: pdf, docx, odt."
  ]
}
```

For better understanding, here is my controller code :

```
public function validation(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        "file" => "required",
        "file.*" => "mimes:pdf,docx,odt"
    ];
    return Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
}

public function check(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(["name"=>$this->validation($request)->errors()->keys(),"error"=>$this->validation($request)->errors()->all()]);
}
```

I don't understand that issue, did I make a mistake or is that a bug from Laravel ? I'm using the 5.6 version by the way.

### UPDATE

I've tried to implement my own rules, I've used a loop since fields are the same array :

```
$rules = [];

foreach($request->input('file') as $key => $value) {
    $rules["file.{$key}"] = 'required|mimes:pdf,docx,odt';
}
return Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
```

**But again it doesn't work WITH the enctype attribute.**

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: you duplicate that  `<input type="file" name="file[]">` , you should use a different name

Comment: But I thought that It wouldn't be a problem since it is an array... Why it would be for the enctype attribute ?

Comment: Maybe not the answer but your form action is bad because you used a double quotations between another double quotation

Comment: Please show `dd($request -> all())`

Comment: `array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "2CpgcclZjuiwVkK8EWHMjFxNrhIM9CK64oiQWcFj"
]` without files set.

Comment: `array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "2CpgcclZjuiwVkK8EWHMjFxNrhIM9CK64oiQWcFj"
  "file" => array:2 [▶]
]` it working with files, but errors are not displayed when they are not set.